# Android - Hide/Remove margins alongwith hiding RecyclerView's items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've some `TextView`s in my `RecyclerView` layout, based on the data which i'm getting from `Firebase` database, i'm hiding some rows using the code below,

```
public void Date(String d){


        dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                LatLonConstructor data = dataSnapshot.getValue(LatLonConstructor.class);

                LatLong = data.getLatLon();

                String SplitOldLatlon[] = LatLong.split(" ");

                Double OldLat = Double.parseDouble(SplitOldLatlon[0]);
                Double OldLon = Double.parseDouble(SplitOldLatlon[1]);

                String LatLon1 = location.getText().toString().trim();
                String SplitNewLatlon[] = LatLon1.split(" ");

                Double NewLat = Double.parseDouble(SplitNewLatlon[0]);
                Double NewLon = Double.parseDouble(SplitNewLatlon[1]);

                double Theta = NewLon - OldLon;
                double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(NewLat))
                        * Math.sin(deg2rad(OldLat))
                        + Math.cos(deg2rad(NewLat))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(OldLat))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(Theta));

                dist = Math.acos(dist);
                dist = rad2deg(dist);
                dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

                String FinalDist = String.valueOf(dist);
                body.setText(FinalDist);

                dist = dist * 1.609;

                if (dist < 1){

                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0,0));

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
```

Now the problem is it is hiding the view but there is a blank space left from where the element was hidden.

I would like to know how to properly hide `RecyclerView`'s item.

Comment: Instead of using margins give padding to that view. Post setting visibility the padding given to that view will also be gone.

Comment: Have you tried adapter.Remove(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: @BENN1TH  is Remove() a predefined method or a something which I've to create......if it is something which I've to create....then yes I've tried this as well with no luck

Comment: Adapter for the recycler  usally has .remove(int) methods.

Just like it has .add()

Comment: @BENN1TH I've tried but it looks the method has been removed from recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that element from the list which you are using for loading data in the recyclerview. Try this if it's not working can you please share your full code.

Comment: Actually loading the data from firebase and i cannot remove it as i validate the data and show it as per the user. So removing the data would not be appropriate

Comment: Can you please share more code so maybe I can help you.

Comment: I think you have to take a temporary list to load the data. like when you get data from firebase, you can store data in this temporary list and when you add this data in new list, you can check your condition. Then use that list to load data in RecyclerView.

Comment: i earlier had this thought but i think then it would take more than usual to load the list as it will first blfetch the data then process it and then pass it to recyclerview. That is why i was wondering if i could directly remove data from my adapter

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes changing height of the parent view helps:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Don't forget to restore row viceversa:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried and now it gives me:- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Viewholder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

To add some margin in place of that view make the view invisible and set its width as per your requirement. I was making the view invisible by view.GONE, it doesn't work as the view is not there so what to set?. The best way is to make it invisible and do whatever you want.

```
linearlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    linearlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(10, 0));
```